# How to resize docker pool size with docker ce 17 (centos)?

Tags: docker, installation

My docker service is running out of space. I’m not able to start docker service now. Reinstall does not help. How can I expand the docker pool `/var/lib/docker` size with **docker ce 17** (centos)? How can I reclaim /var/lib/docker without starting docker?
Solution like modifying /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage seem not valid now (not such file at all).

```
$df
/dev/xvda3 207710036 29473308 167662600 15% /
/dev/xvda5 25165824 19947980 0 100% /var/lib/docker
```

**Solution:**
umount xvda5 and it works fine now.

Comment: Your partition itself is full? The the workaround would be to move this to another external driver and resize `xvda3` and add size to `xvda5` or you will need to attach another drive and mount `/var/lib/docker`. Or you can even remove the mount point and let the folder mount on `xvda3` directly.

Comment: Yes you are right, I umount xvda5 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your partition itself is full

The the workaround would be to move this to another external driver and resize `xvda3` and add size to `xvda5` or you will need to attach another drive and mount /var/lib/docker. Or you can even remove the mount point and let the folder mount on `xvda3` directly

Simplest would be to unmount `xvda5`, this will let your `/var/lib/docker` to go to `xvda3`